# Convert large dataset so that it is split into files along a different dimension?

Tags: python

I have a large dataset (~200gb) of data, where each csv file contains data across the entire region for one point in time. What is the fastest way to convert it so that each file contains data for one grid point across the entire time period? Ideally, each file would end up as a 1 dimensional compressed npz file.

Comment: The correct answer really depends on the structure of the data. Could you post here first few lines?

Comment: There are 3600 rows and 1800 columns, normal csv file ie 1.234567, 2.345678, etc